# How to: Using a custom class as a Map parameter

Tags: java, class, dictionary

I'm getting the nullpointerexception in the line 9 (the one with a comment).

I'm trying to use the method as a parametre in the shoppingCart class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ShoppingCart {

    private Map<String, Purchase> ShoppingCart;

    public void add (String product, int price) {
        Purchase purchase = new Purchase(product, 1, price);
        ShoppingCart.put(product, purchase);         //this line doesn't work!
    }

    public int price() {
        Collection<Purchase> total = shoppingCart.values();

        }   
}
```

The constructor for the Purchase method is:

```
 public Purchase(String product, int amount, int price) {
```

The Main tries to add the product to the shoppingCart which causes the nullpointerexception:

```
ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();
cart.add("milk, 3);
```

I suppose I'm missing something fundamental when it comes to Maps. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is in Finnish, so had to do some translation. Will do more carefully next time.

Comment: Create the Map object. Also follow camel casing for variable names.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to instantiate your map `ShoppingCart = new HashMap<String, Purchase>()`.

By the way, in java, variables always start with a lower case letter (camelCase), only classes  start with an upper case (PascalCase)

Comment: Amateur mistake :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You never create a `ShoppingCart` object. This is not like C++ in which the object is created when you define the variable; all variables are in fact references to objects and you need to explicity create the objects (with `new`).

BTW, this line causes a compilation error (shoppingCart should be lowercase)

```
private Map<String, Purchase> ShoppingCart;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you don't initialize your shoppingCart:

```
private Map<String, Purchase> ShoppingCart= new HashMap<String,Purchase>()
```